# During rolling upgrade/restart, how to detect when a kafka broker is "done"?

Tags: apache-kafka, upgrade

I need to automate a rolling restart of a kafka cluster (3 kafka brokers). I can easily do it manually - restart one after the other, while checking the log to see when it's fine (e.g., when the new process has joined the cluster).

What is a good way to automate this check? How can I ask the broker whether it's up and running, connected to its peers, all topics up-to-date and such? In my restart script, I have access to the metrics, but to be frank, I did not really see one there which gives me a clear picture.

Another way would be to ask what a good "readyness" probe would be that does not simply check some TCP/IP port, but looks at the actual server...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest exposing JMX metrics and tracking the following for cluster health

- the controller count (must be 1 over the whole cluster)
- under replicated partitions (should be zero for healthy cluster)
- unclean leader elections (if you don't disable this in `server.properties` make sure there are none in the metric counts)
- ISR shrinks within a reasonable time period, like 10 minute window (should be none)

Also, [Yelp has tooling for rolling restarts](https://github.com/Yelp/kafka-utils#rolling-restart-a-cluster) implemented in Python, which requires Jolokia JMX Agents installed on the brokers, and it polls the metrics to make sure some of the above conditions are true

Comment: Think that Yelps solution is only when your cluster is in non-security mode. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I don't think the Kafka security protocol matters. The script seems to use SSH and HTTP .

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your cluster was healthy at the beginning of the restart operation, at a minimum, after each broker restart, you should ensure that the under-replicated partition count returns to zero before restarting the next broker.

As the previous responders mentioned, there is existing code out there to automate this. I don’t use Jolikia, myself, but my solution (which I’m working on now) also uses JMX metrics.

Answer (score 1):

[Kakfa Utils](https://github.com/Yelp/kafka-utils) by Yelp is one of the best tools that can be used to detect when a kafka broker is "done". Specifically, [kafka_rolling_restart](https://github.com/Yelp/kafka-utils/tree/master/kafka_utils/kafka_rolling_restart) is the tool which gets broker details from zookeeper and URP (Under Replicated Partitions) metrics from each broker. When a broker is restarted, total URPs across Kafka cluster is periodically collected and when it goes to zero, it restarts another broker. The controller broker is restarted at the last.